# Macbook not connecting to WIFI

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook

I have been having this problem all week.

My Macbook aluminium can't see my wifi network. I have changed the channel to one that isn't being used by neighbours and my iphone picks it up straight away. In other words, the router is fine. It's just the macbook can't see it. This is driving me nuts if anyone can help...

My airport card details...

```
 Card Type: AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x8D)
  Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.36.1)
  Locale:   ETSI
  Supported PHY Modes:  802.11 a/b/g/n
  Supported Channels:   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140
  Wake On Wireless: Supported
```

The funny thing is that is was intermitent on Saturday. I had to keep restarting router and it worked for about 5 minutes, now it doesn't connect or see it at all. Tried using kisMAC and it can't see network either.

Thanks,
C

Comment: Can your see other networks? Or is the wifi completely dead?

Comment: I can see other networks, just not my own, which I know is working because the iphone picks it up? IT's def problem with Macbook.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a WEP wi-fi account, put a `$` at the front of the password.

So if the password is `00000000`, make it `$00000000`. This is a known issue on WEP security on Mac OS X, but it's specific to certain versions of OS X and may not affect you.

Comment: Its WAP2. I use Snow Leopard and everything has been fine for a year until last week. Strange.